# XmlNode Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I need your help. I am new to xml and need to get its attribute.

I have a mailbox(XmlNode) that is represented by the following InnerXml

`<Mailbox Id="1" Name="user1@domain.com" />`

I need to access the Id attribute using this piece of code

```
mailbox.Attribute["Id"].Value
```

but it throws null reference exception.
I haven't found any solution, as I can't make any changes to the

....mailbox.Attribute["Id"].Value .....part of code

can anyone help me?

Comment: The code you pasted represents the InnerXml or OuterXml? If it represents InnerXml, can you show what is in the OuterXml?

Comment: How do you acquire reference to `mailbox`?

Comment: (Withdrew my comment about case sensitivity on `Id` -- the font was misleading me; it looks like capital I was used.. In that case, I think Wiktor's question is on target: whatever mailbox represents, it isn't the `<Mailbox>` element shown above. (At least it probably isn't a namespace issue; attributes don't take default namepaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this piece of code

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Your_XML_Path");
string id;
  while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "Mailbox")
                {
                    id = reader.GetAttribute(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Try this and let me know if u have any doubts or if this code doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so I checked the OuterXml(actually didn't know there's a difference)

```
<Mailboxes><Mailbox Id="1" Name="user1@domain.com" />...
```

that was the reason why it didn't work.
so now using

`mailbox.SelectSingleNode("//Mailboxes/Mailbox").Attributes["Id"].Value`

everything works correctly.